# __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am saving data in csv using pandas dataframe.

```
    new_data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in results:
    Customerid = i[0]
    JOININGDATE = i[1]
    jdate = i[1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    td=datetime.datetime.now().date()
    bd=datetime.date(JOININGDATE.year,JOININGDATE.month,JOININGDATE.day)
    age_years=int((td-bd).days /365.25)
    BuisnessAge = age_years
    data = pd.DataFrame(Customerid,jdate,BuisnessAge, columns=['CustomerID', 'JOININGDATE', 'BuisnessAge'])
    new_data = new_data.append(data,sort=False)
    new_data = new_data.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.DataFrame(...)` (roughly) leads to `pd.DataFrame.__init__(...)`, that's why `__init__` is part of the error message.

The actual error is this: The [signature](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) of `pd.DataFrame(...)` is:

```
pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

You called:

```
pd.DataFrame(Customerid,jdate,BuisnessAge, columns=['CustomerID', 'JOININGDATE', 'BuisnessAge'])
```

So:

```
data=Customerid,
index=jdate,
columns=BuisnessAge,
columns=['CustomerID', 'JOININGDATE', 'BuisnessAge']
```

Thus you defined `columns` multiple times, which combined leads to your error `__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'columns'`.

Comment: I got the solution. I replaced                                                                                              data = pd.DataFrame(Customerid,jdate,BuisnessAge, columns=['CustomerID', 'JOININGDATE', 'BuisnessAge']) to  data = pd.DataFrame([[Customerid,jdate,BuisnessAge]], columns=['CustomerID', 'JOININGDATE', 'BuisnessAge'])